# Setting LineHeight for MarkdownTextBlock control

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

In UWP there is a LineHeight property for TextBlock control. I am looking for similar functionality for MarkdownTextBlock control in Windows Community Toolkit. How can I set the space between lines for the MarkdownTextBlock control?

Comment: The default MarkdownTextBlock control doesn't have the `LineHeight` property. You could submit a 'Feature Request'  on [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?category_id=193402). Another way is you could download the [open source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MarkdownTextBlock) and add some code to achieve your target by yourself. Then you could compile a custom version of Community Toolkit. In your project, you could add reference to this custom version Community Toolkit library.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Thank you very much.